# Connect with Powershell to Dynamics CRM online with application user

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I would like to use Powershell cmdlets to work with Microsoft CRM 365 online. I can connect with `Get-CrmConnection` using my username and password, but I would like to use an Application User instead. This is the same Application user that I am using to access the CRM Web API.

I am unable to generate the correct connection string that will authenticate the Application user.

[image: Application user details]

Comment: Post your code!

Comment: I doubt you can interact with CRM Powershell using non-interactive service accounts (Application users) as the same way as interactive users. Since Application users uses AppId unlike regular users with username/password..

Answer (score 0):

If your intension is keep the credential secret every time you run your PowerShell script you could use InteractiveMode [(microsoft link)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/xrm-tooling/use-powershell-cmdlets-xrm-tooling-connect#use-the-cmdlet-to-connect-to--apps)

with it the CRM Login will prompt and ask for your credentials

Hope it helps - M.Acosta.D